# Cypress, как выбрать из выпадающего списка регион?

Tags: javascript, test-automation

Пытаюсь выбрать из выпадающего списка регион, но сам импут со списком через гет не могуй найти. Может быть как-то по другому это делается?

```
.get('#region')
.select('div > div:nth-child(1)')

[![Код элемента со списком регионов на скрине.][1]][1]
```

[image: []

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get('input').eq([тут порядковый номер инпута - со скрина 3(с 0
считает)]).click() 
cy.contains('Вписать искомый видимый текст из списка').click()
```

Сам ищу ответ на то, как выбирать из списков, если в них есть одинаковые значения. 2 выпадающих списка - в них одно и то же.
Если делать как я - то выбрать можно только то что выдно в выпадающем списке.